# TS2307: Cannot find module (all modules) - after moving folders

Tags: angular, npm, build, angular-components, angular-module

I decided to moving folders in order to organize modules as follows:
[image: Structure of catalogs]

Automatically was changed `app.module.ts`:

[app.module.ts with important part of debug.log](https://gist.github.com/plkpiotr/9ba83778a5f5b1aa139f0c5f5256f0b6)

But, when I try to use `npm install` or `ng serve` I get:

```
ERROR in : Can't resolve all parameters for EmployeesComponent in C:/Users/admin/Desktop/erp-mes-frontend/src/app/staff/employees/employees/employees.component.ts: (?, [object Object]).
src/app/staff/employees/employees/employees.component.ts(2,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../services/employee.service'.
src/app/staff/employees/employees/employees.component.ts(4,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../types'.
src/app/staff/teams/teams/teams.component.ts(3,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../services/team.service'.
src/app/staff/teams/teams/teams.component.ts(4,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../types'.
src/app/staff/teams/team/team.component.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../services/team.service'.
src/app/staff/teams/team/team.component.ts(4,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../types'.
src/app/production/tasks/tasks/tasks.component.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../services/task.service'.
src/app/production/tasks/tasks/tasks.component.ts(4,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../types'.
src/app/production/tasks/task/task.component.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../services/task.service'.
src/app/production/tasks/task/task.component.ts(4,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../types'.
src/app/production/tasks/add-task/add-task.component.ts(2,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../types'.
src/app/production/tasks/add-task/add-task.component.ts(3,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../services/task.service'.
src/app/production/tasks/add-task/add-task.component.ts(5,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../services/employee.service'.
```

etc...

In addition to this IntelliJ suggests me:

`TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'AppModule' in app.module.ts`

and:

`ng: Component 'AppComponent' is not included in a module and will not be available inside a template. Consider adding it to a NgModule declaration`

or for other components similar error like:

`ng: Can't resolve all parameters for TasksComponent in C:/Users/admin/Desktop/erp-mes-frontend/src/app/production/tasks/tasks/tasks.component.ts: (?, [object Object])`

Could someone please assist?

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? You moved files around. The error says that these files no longer exist. They don't indeed -- you just moved them. What about the error is puzzling you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When moving files around, you have to ensure that all file references are updated to account for the file's new location. Did you just move files and not update them accordingly?

Go to `app.module.ts` and any other file that contains imports/exports and ensure the file URL is updated with the new locations.

For example, `import { Module } from './settings/module';` would have to be updated to `import { Module } from './new_folder/settings/module';` or other appropriate folder structure.

If you're using an IDE, it should point out incorrect locations to you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ;) Thanks to you I noticed that some of imports in the components after refactoring are really weird...

Comment: No problem. When moving anything, your next step should be to update it's location references. Also, a good IDE could allow you to mass refactor matching URLs for each location update.

Comment: I was sure that IntelliJ can deal with it but maybe repeated names of folders and repeatedly moved modules get in the way. Or maybe, natural perversity of inanimate objects ;)
If manual changes helps me, I will give you the best answer ;) Wish me luck :)